# Geometrical interpretation of $\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\alpha}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, centroid

What is the geometrical interpretation of this quantity $$\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\alpha}$$
such that $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2)$

For example, this is the abscissa of the centroid of the arcs of the unit circle centered at the origin of angle $2\alpha$ and symmetric with respect to the axis of abscissa.

Is there any other geometrical interpretation of this quantity or can we characterize this centroid by another method

Comment: You may take $\alpha$ as an arc length corresponding to an angle $\alpha$ of a unit circle.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: Thanks @Khosrotash but I think my question is different

Comment: Some of proof are there by geometric concept...take a look ,maybe help you

Comment: Note that $\sin(\alpha)/\alpha$ is also called the [unnormalized sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Comment: @Bernstein: I do not think there is restriction for $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2)$

Comment: Please do not use inappropriate tags. Nothing here with linear algebra or differential geometry.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for your remark, I have read your courses on Diff Geo it was very nice for me. many thanks with a lot of admiration :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the previous hints, in a circle of radius $R$, take lines from the center, forming an angle $2\alpha$. The lines intersect the circle at $A$ and $B$. Then the length of the arc between them is $2R\alpha$, and the length of the chord is $2R\sin\alpha$. So $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\alpha}=\frac{|\overparen{AB}|}{|AB|}$$ is the ratio of the cord length to the arc length for two points on the circle, forming an angle $2\alpha$ from the origin.
** As requested** I've added an image. The ratio is the length of the blue line to the length of the red arc.
[image]

Comment: I think you need put picture

Comment: @DDD4C4U I've modified my answer as requested

Answer (score 0):

When we consider one half of the arc only:

$$ \bar{x}= \dfrac{\int x ds}{\int ds} = \dfrac{\int x ds}{\int ds} $$
with $ s = R \theta,\,$ the centroid $x$ location is

$$ \dfrac{\int_0^\alpha R \cos \theta R d\theta}{\int _0^\alpha R d\theta} =R\dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha}$$

similarly for  $ y= R \cos \theta $

$$ \bar{y}=R\dfrac{\;1-\cos \alpha}{\alpha}$$

Centroid locus for a half one side extending arc is shown.

So $\alpha $ need not be bounded.

$$ \alpha\rightarrow \infty, \bar{r} \rightarrow 0$$

[image]